# How can I install using cargo when offline?

Tags: installation, rust, rust-cargo

I want to use bat and lsd in my work area.

But my company's Centos 6 Linux server is disconnected from the internet for security.

But we can do it that is install something that is helping to work.

```
> cargo install --locked bat
    Updating crates.io index
warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): failed to resolve address for github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution; class=Net (12)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): failed to resolve address for github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution; class=Net (12)
error: failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  failed to resolve address for github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution; class=Net (12)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

The directions below aren't much different for any other crate.

1. Download the repository:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/sharkdp/bat.git --depth 1 --branch v0.18.1
   cd bat
   ```

   This just gets the `0.18.1` version of the [`bat`](https://crates.io/crates/bat) crate.
2. Use [`cargo vendor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-vendor.html) to download and bundle up the package's dependencies on the local machine:

   ```
   cargo vendor
   ```

   - optionally specify a [toolchain](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/concepts/toolchains.html) if different than the other machine (i.e. `cargo +<TOOLCHAIN> vendor`)
   - optionally specify a [target](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/targets/index.html) if different than the other machine (i.e. `cargo vendor --target <TARGET>`)

   Be sure to **follow the directions at the end** to create/add to the `.cargo/config.toml` file. You can also inspect all the dependencies that are now in the `vendor/` directory.
3. Zip up and transfer the whole current directory to the other machine.
4. Use [`cargo install`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-install.html) to install it:

   ```
   cargo install --offline --path <PATH>
   ```

   - use `--path` to tell it the directory to install from
   - use `--offline` to prevent it from accessing the network for any reason

Comment: How are they going to clone a GitHub repository without internet connection?

Comment: @mkrieger1 how are you going to get *any files* with out an internet connection?  You use a separate machine connected to the internet.